# Can I use Tor to make Tox chats anonymous?

Tags: chat

[Tox](https://tox.im) is an open-source protocol for encrypted chat.

It is not anonymous.

My research lead me here:

[secure communication needs to be anonymous #356](https://github.com/irungentoo/toxcore/issues/356)

Can I use Tor for this?

Answer (score 1):

Tor is designed to protect your network communications. While you can run a chat system over Tor, it can't defend against accidental application leaks. You'd have to fully review the application itself to make sure.